# Android Studio + Flutter: identifier suggestion not relative

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

See attachment. The top list of suggestions not relative to `alignment`. This happened after I upgraded Android Studio from 3 to 4. I'm sure when using Android Studio 3, the suggestion is smart and show relative items at top of list.

(BTW: this also happened to Vscode)

[image]